# Solving a recurrence using master method when g(n)=log(n)

Tags: recurrence, master-theorem

I'm trying to solve the recurrence f(n)=2f(n/2)+logn when f(1)=1 and n is a power of 2.  I think that I should be able to do this using the master method. I've seen this before, but never with log.  Can I get some help getting started, please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question not a programming question.

Comment: I posted here because I've only ever encountered the master theorem in the context of computer science.  Should I delete the question and ask it on math stack exchange instead?

Comment: Note that [logarithms grow more slowly than any positive-power polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial). This should help you to choose the correct case.

Answer (score 0):

One trick that’s often useful here is to replace the log n term with something that grows strictly faster or slower and to see what you get. For example, your recurrence is bounded from above and below, respectively, by these recurrences:

> A(n) = 2A(n / 2) + √n.
>
> B(n) = 2A(n / 2) + 1.

What do these solve to? What does that tell you about your recurrence?